# Raising to the T in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, lambda-calculus, neural-networks, notation

What does it mean when in a machine learning paper there is
$(arg)^{T}$, what does the T does to an arg [image: 3b1b] in this 3b1b video on neural networks he puts the: $(w^{l-1})^{T}$

Comment: In what context is this? could you provide the paper so we can see it ourselves? Or even better - quote it. Anyhow, raising to $T$ could be the transpose matrix when in context of linear algebra maths, but it also could just be a regular number and raising some other number to its power. Or, it could be something the authors of the paper defined themselves

Comment: Yeah most likely transpose of a vector or matrix.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more context.

Answer (score 4):

The notation $A^T$ stands for the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of a matrix. It is not specific to machine learning, but rather standard notation in linear algebra. Other notations are sometimes used, for example $A'$.

A related operation is the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) $A^*$. The transpose and adjoint are equal for real matrices.